# Why does this code have a "one off error"?

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling, logic

I am building a GWT component to behave much like the comments box here on stackoverflow, and other sites. I am trying to register listeners for `KeyPress`, `Change` and `ONPASTE` events that will update my status line with number of characters remaining, etc.

It works except it is always one character behind the actual number of characters in the text area. I set the max number of characters to 10. When I type the first character it still says, "10 characters remaining". It doesn't update the status line until I type the second character and then it is one off, it says 9 characters remaining when the second character is typed.

When I `BACKSPACE` or `DELETE`, it is also one off, when there are no characters it still says "9 characters remaining" until I press the `BACKSPACE` or `DELETE` a second time.

I am getting this behavior in both Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer on Windows. So I think I am not registering something correctly.

I know this has something to do with when the events are getting fired, but I have spend hours on trying to diagnose this behavior and have run out of ideas.

Here is where I am registering the event handlers, the complete code is [BoundedTextAreaWithFeedback](https://gist.github.com/857460/2d91c50fcd37d62dd33d72f2b799536020399413).

```
private void registerHandlers()
{
    final BoundedTextAreaWithFeedback outer = this;
    this.textArea.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler()
    {
        public void onChange(final ChangeEvent changeEvent)
        {
            outer.validate();
        }
    });
    this.textArea.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler()
    {
        public void onKeyPress(final KeyPressEvent keyPressEvent)
        {
            outer.validate();
        }
    });
    this.panel.addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler()
    {
        public void onFocus(final FocusEvent focusEvent)
        {
            outer.textArea.setFocus(true);
        }
    });

    // capture paste events
    this.textArea.sinkEvents(Event.ONPASTE);
}
```

Here is the `validate()` method.

```
private boolean validate()
{
    final boolean isValid;
    final int len = this.textArea.getText().length();
    if (len < this.minLength)
    {
        this.status.setText("Enter at least " + this.minLength + " characters.");
        this.status.setStyleName("input-status-underflow");
        isValid = false;
    }
    else if (len > this.maxLength)
    {
        this.status.setText(this.maxLength - len + " characters remaining");
        this.status.setStyleName("input-status-overflow");
        isValid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        this.status.setText(this.maxLength - len + " characters remaining");
        this.status.setStyleName("input-status-ok");
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just started adding every `addXXXHandler()` until one worked.

```
this.textArea.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler()
{
    public void onKeyUp(final KeyUpEvent event)
    {
        outer.validate();
    }
});
```

Seems to have done the trick.

Here is the [working code](https://gist.github.com/857460), `CTRL-V` and paste from context menu also work now.

Comment: This works because the letter is not added to the TextArea until the key is released.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [DeferredCommand](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/DeferredCommand.html) to execute the validation code. I believe the problem is that when the event is firing, they character is *not yet* added to the text area. The DeferredCommand will not execute until any pending event handlers have finished, allowing the length of the text to be calculated correctly.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691684/gxt-keylistener-componentkeydown-immediately-closes-messagebox-alert) for an example of using a DeferredCommand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it did indirectly solve another issue I was having with pasting from a context menu, in GWT 2.2.x DeferredCommand is `deprecated` I used [Scheduler.scheduleDeferred()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleDeferred%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand%29) to get the status line to update when paste from a context menu happened. But it did put me on the right track for the other problem.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it. Haven't used GWT since 1.7, crazy how fast things change. :)

Comment: Me either, last time I was using it was 1.3.x :-)